# UITableViewController isEditing

Tags: swift, uikit

'isEditing = true' calls 'setEditing' method, but doesn't change value of 'isEditing' property of TableViewController class

Is that how it should be? or i do something wrong?

PS if i don't override setEditing func, everything is ok

Example:

```
@IBAction func setEditMode(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (isEditing) {
        sender.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
        isEditing = false
        print(isEditing) // false
    } else {
        sender.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        isEditing = true
        print(isEditing) // false
    }
}

override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) { 
    tableView.isEditing = editing
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since you figured out that you forget to call `super.setEditing` you should delete the question.

Comment: stackoverflow: We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge... Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking.  Can you show me where it says that I should delete the topic? i don't want to be blocked

Comment: The answer below doesn't come close to answering your question so it's of no value to anyone. If you don't want to delete the question that's fine. But you should at least remove your "answer" from your question and post a proper answer below if you think it might help future users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

super.setEditing was missed

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.isEditing = editing
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Use this code: -----

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
   self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
})
```

or use delegate method :---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```